# Update lits after dialog close in Vuejs project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a list that displays items on a page, on the same page you can open a dialog where you are able to add items to the list. When I close the dialog I want the list to re-render to also show the latest added item.

Parent:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item in listItems" :key="item.id"></div>
    <app-card-grid-work 
        :items="listItems">
    </app-card-grid-work>

    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
        <app-fab slot="activator"></app-fab>
        <app-add-work @closeDialog="getWork()"></app-add-work>       
    </v-dialog>
<template>

export default {
   data() {
    return {
      listItems: [],
    },
    methods: {
        getWork(){
            axios
                .get("/workads")
                .then(res => {
                    const data = res.data;
                    const ads = [];
                    for (let id in data) {
                        const ad = data[id];
                        ads.push(ad);
                    }
                this.listItems = ads;
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Child (app-add-work)

```
<template>
    <v-btn
        @click="onSubmit"
        :disabled="!valid">
        Skapa
    </v-btn>
<template>

<script>
export default {
    //...
    methods:{
        onSubmit(){
            this.$emit('closeDialog')
        }
    },
    //...
};
</script>
```

Comment: what does `.getWork()` do?

Comment: Yeah sorry i forgot to explain, this does nothing at the moment, i tried to make an axios call to get the list updated on the emit.

Comment: What is the issue then? It seems like you just need to update `listItem` object after the request is done successful.

Comment: so adding the axios get() call inside the getWork function should do the trick? Because this does not work?    `getWork(){
      axios
        .get("/workads")
        .then(res => {
          const data = res.data;
          const ads = [];
          for (let id in data) {
            const ad = data[id];
            ads.push(ad);
          }
          this.listItems = ads;
        })`

Comment: Please just update your question with the code and the exact error you got. "Doesn't work" doesn't really help and it will be much easier to read.

Comment: Okey thanks for the help by the way, i updated the post with the code. I dont get any errors but the list does not have the latest added items until i reload the page.

Comment: Things to check: do you get response at all? is it expected(contains all items that should be there)? is `listItem` value updated as intended after `getWork()` is done?